# IntelliJ Grails 3 Project: Unable to Run Grails project

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, java-8

I recently installed IntelliJ onto my machine after many unsuccessful attempt to get GGTS working reliably. So far the error messages were clear and easy to resolve after I imported my Grails project. GGTS had forced me to downgrade from Grails 3 to 2 because, at the time, GGTS does not seem to support Grails 3. I ran into issues after pointing IntelliJ to Grails 3, but restarting IntelliJ seemed to fix those problems. Now, however, I can't get my project to start and I get the following error:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java" ...;C:\dev\grails-3.0.4\lib\xalan\serializer\jars\serializer-2.7.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.grails.cli.GrailsCli run-app
Error |
Problem updating profiles from origin git repository (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Could not checkout tag for Grails release [3.0.4]: repository not found: C:\Users\Randeep\.grails\repository (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
Error |
Error occurred running Grails CLI: No profile found for name [web]. (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Note the "**Problem updating profiles from origin git repository**" message. This is a git project, but I don't know why IntelliJ is trying to do any git operations (I don't want it to, I just want it to run my project).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a lot going on behind the scenes with grails here. The CLI (command line interface) is trying to load a **profile** called web. Basically grails creates a .grails folder in your home directory that contains a set of default profiles (see ~/.grails/repository/profiles).

Somehow this folder got corrupted or modified on my system and the web profile, which is the default profile, disappeared. To fix this I simply deleted the .grails folder from my home directory, ran grails, and it regenerated.

**Edit:** Deleting your .grails folder may have undesirable behavior if other projects are using data within it, so try deleting the profiles folder first.

Comment: `.grails` can contain more important files that are either used by the framework, other projects or users (you can define external config files in there). Try deleting the `profiles` folder instead.

Comment: Actually... I cannot make this edit. I'm thinking back to last night and I think the first thing I did was delete the profile folder and I wasn't able to get it regenerate. I need to investigate to more to see what the top level delete should be, but let me know if you know

Comment: I did faced similar problem for angular profile in grails 3.1.3. For me `gradle clean` command worked.

Comment: Seconding the answer submitted by @hemu, the following worked for me (assumes you have sdkman installed)...

`sdk install gradle`,  `gradle clean`, `grails run-app`
`

Answer (score 2):

I got this error message too after I delete ~/.grails ~/.gradle from my home directory.

Thoses directories seems won't created again for some reason, and grails clean isn't work at the same time.

This how I fixed it, hope it helps.

1. set up **JAVA_HOME** / **GRAILS_HOME** variables.
2. cd GRAILS_HOME (ie. /etc/grails/grails-3.1.4 )
3. execute 'bin/grails'
4. **create-profile web**
5. grails will try to create a new web profile, and start downloading dependency jars.
6. exit. & done.

ps. my environment.

- jdk 1.7.0_4
- grails 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ is trying to download a Grails profile called 'web' and it is unable. Enable --stacktrace and dig into the problem.
Or Create a new project in IntelliJ and point it to your source.
Note: Your project should be a Grails 3.0.X to use profiles.

Comment: I tried looking up the process for "enable --stacktrace" but couldn't find anything. Do you know how that works?

Comment: To follow up on this question, "--stacktrace" is an option that can be specified on the Grails command line. I'm not sure how to configure IntelliJ (or Eclipse) to do this

Comment: Actually I was able to fix this, see the accepted answer (my own). Grails wasn't trying to download anything, it was trying to read a profile entry in my .gradle folder

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across this question when my Grails 3.2.8 app was reporting a similar problem for react.

```
Error occurred running Grails CLI: No profile found for name [react]
```

I do not have a `.grails/profile` folder, for whatever reason, and didn't want to trash the whole `.grails` folder right off the bat, so I ended up :

1. reimporting my project into the IDE
2. refreshed the grails dependencies
3. cleaned the grails project

and it worked for me.